# MYSQL PHP Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I understand how prepared statements work and I need to insert 2 million rows so in this case using a prepared statement is the best option for me. My question and problem is I have a compound unique key on row2 and row3 so I can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in the prepared statement fine but what if I wish to use a condition and only update if the lastupdated DATE is before the comparison date? Without a prepared statement I can just use a simple IF in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but I can not seem to implement it with a prepared statement since the variables are bound and will be set within the loop after the prepared statement is created.

```
$link = new mysqli(db_host,db_user,db_pass,db_db);
if($link->connect_errno){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL.";
}

if(!($stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO table(`id`,`lastupdated`,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`,`col6`,`col7`,`col8`,`col9`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))){
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
}
```

Comment: If you can use an `IF` in the ordinary statement, you should be able to do the same thing in a prepared statement. Show the code that tries to do this ad tell us the error you get.

Comment: If you have to load millions of records and its not a recurring occurance I would say look into the `LOAD DATA INFILE` mysql syntax would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[values()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function could be used in this case, I believe, as it will return the actual value passed via placeholder at query execution.

Or you can simply bind the same value twice, first for the VALUES section and second for the UPDATE

Comment: if(!($stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO productsearch(`PROGRAMNAME`,`LASTUPDATED`,`NAME`,`SKU`,`MANUFACTURER`,`CATEGORY`,`CURRENCY`,`SALEPRICE`,`PRICE`,`IMAGEURL`,`SEARCH`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=IF($lastupdated < VALUES(LASTUPDATED),VALUES(LASTUPDATED),$lastupdated)"))){
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
}

Comment: problem is since variables are bound $lastupdated wont make any since in the preapared IF clause

Comment: You should replace `$lastupdated` with placeholders and bind them like the other values.

Comment: so if I use ? in place of $lastupdated how will the statement know I am referencing $lastupdated as opposed to the other variables?

Comment: @RobNHood you are confusing values(field) with `field`. Former one represents entered value, while latter one represents existing value.

Comment: Yes I feel like an idiot... I'm comparing the same values whereas I should be comparing the column with variable ie LASTUPDATED = VALUES('LASTUPDATED'). Your Common Sense was right. and to think I googled this for most of the day.